# Block a thread without blocking the normal controls

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am making a simple GUI program, which will give you a particular list of files matching the search criteria provided by the user.
Sometimes the searching takes a lot of time(10-15s). So I called the Search function in a new thread. Also in the function, there is some code, which can only run after the newly created thread is aborted. Therefore I used Join() function to block the execution of the program until the thread is finished. But using this causes the application to hang. Can I have a solution to this problem.

Comment: You might want a completion event?

Comment: Just don't call Join().  A BackgroundWorker or Task can let you run code on the UI thread when the operation completed.

Comment: what I basically want is that the thread should not hang up the application, the normal message loop should keep on executing.

Comment: Whats your target framework? For 4.5 use the new async/await feature which is simple and straightforward and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the background worker control

See here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798034.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your UI hangs because the UI thread is waiting for the new Thread to finish - essentially, you have the same problem as if you ran the search on the UI thread directly.

The solution: Don't wait for the new thread. In order to do something to the UI once the thread is done, you can call back into the UI code from that thread by using Control.Invoke. For example, if your form is called `m_myForm`, you can do this on the background thread to call a function on your form on the UI thread, passing the result:

```
m_myForm.Invoke((Action)() => m_myForm.DoSomethingWithSearchResult(result));
```

Alternatively, you can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead of using Thread directly. This will help you run something on a non-UI thread, and raises an event when the work is done, and takes care of correctly synchronizing between the UI and the background work.